# Unable to use listener in doInBackground()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, listener

In my `asyncTask` `doInBackground()` method I want to handle exception by making a toast. But I am unable to do so, and this is exception I get. Why is that? 
P.S. I can do it in `onPreExecute()` and `onPostExecute()`.

```
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error     occured while executing doInBackground()
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at com.xxx.MenuActivity$ImageCount.setView(MenuActivity.java:208)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at com.xxx.StringAsyncRetriever.getData(StringAsyncRetriever.java:101)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at com.xxx.StringAsyncRetriever.getData(StringAsyncRetriever.java:95)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at com.xxx.StringAsyncRetriever.doInBackground(StringAsyncRetriever.java:44)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at com.xxx.StringAsyncRetriever.doInBackground(StringAsyncRetriever.java:1)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
02-04 09:43:45.190: E/AndroidRuntime(19308):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a ui action inside `doInBackground`, so in case of exception return a value that can be checked in the `onPostExecute` .. based on this value show your toast

Answer (score 0):

the answer of Nunu is correct. But if you want to handle exception in doInBackground method and show some toast and continue with some other operations in the catch clause or in the method itself you should use onProgressUpdate method. It run on UI thread too and can be called as many times as you wish inside doInBackground. You need publishProgress to perform call to onProgressUpdate method.

OnPostExecute is called only once after the doInBackground is finished.

Here is the docs for AsynchTask:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html